# Approaches to syncing web application data with users' desktops

Tags: web-applications, google-drive-api, dropbox, data-synchronization, atom-feed

We have a web application in the academic research sector that receives data from scientific instruments and stores it. It would be cool to be able to automatically synchronise this data with users' desktops - at least one way (web -> desktop) but the other way would be potentially useful too. Depending on the deployment, the total amount of data for a user ranges between a few hundred megabytes and several terabytes. (We don't need to solve every case - this is "it would be cool", not "this is mission critical")

### Google Drive/Dropbox/...

The first thought was to replicate the data on Google Drive or Dropbox.

Advantages:

- Rock solid desktop sync apps
- Comfortable, familiar technology to users (in many instances, users have institutional Google accounts)

Disadvantages:

- These APIs aren't really designed for simply channelling data through. We'd probably have to store *all* the data there, which gets expensive, or manage things like deleting old data.
- Google Drive looks like a hassle to integrate with (registering an app on the Chrome Web Store...)
- Need to manage these external credentials etc.

### Atom/RSS feed?

The further thought occurred that we could perhaps set up an Atom feed for each user, and maybe there are Atom clients that can trawl feeds and download all the links to a local directory? I haven't investigated. Is this feasible? We're already using Atom in some instances to get data *into* our app, but we obviously don't use a desktop client for that.

We'd really want to use existing apps, and would need to support at least Windows (XP+) and OS X. We don't want to be in the business of writing any desktop software.

### Other?

If there are two approaches, are there others?